# Joining table issue with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using the following query to obtain some sales figures. The problem is that it is returning the wrong data.

I am joining together three tables `tbl_orders` `tbl_orderitems` `tbl_payment`. The `tbl_orders` table holds summary information, the `tbl_orderitems` holds the items ordered and the `tbl_payment` table holds payment information regarding the order. Multiple payments can be placed against each order.

I am trying to get the sum of the items `sum(mon_orditems_pprice)`, and also the amount of items sold `count(uid_orderitems)`.

When I run the following query against a specific order number, which I know has 1 order item. It returns a count of 2 and the sum of two items.

```
Item                       ProdTotal    ProdCount
Westvale Climbing Frame    1198         2
```

This order has two payment records held in the `tbl_payment` table, which is causing the double count. If I remove the payment table join it reports the correct figures, or if I select an order which has a single payment it works as well. Am I missing something, I am tired!!??

```
SELECT 
  txt_orditems_pname,
  SUM(mon_orditems_pprice) AS prodTotal,
  COUNT(uid_orderitems) AS prodCount
FROM dbo.tbl_orders
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orderitems ON (dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders = dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_orderid)
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_payment ON (dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders = dbo.tbl_payment.uid_pay_orderid)
WHERE
  uid_orditems_orderid = 61571
GROUP BY
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname
ORDER BY
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Drill down Table columns

```
dbo.tbl_payment.bit_pay_paid (1/0) Has this payment been paid, yes no
dbo.tbl_orders.bit_order_archive (1/0) Is this order archived, yes no
dbo.tbl_orders.uid_order_webid (integer) Web Shop's ID
dbo.tbl_orders.bit_order_preorder (1/0) Is this a pre-order, yes no
YEAR(dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp) (2012) Sales year
dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_status (varchar) Is the order dispatched, awaiting delivery
dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_pcatid (integer) Product category ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal behavior, if you remove grouping clause you'll see that there really are 2 rows after joining and they both have 599 as a `mon_orditems_pprice` hence the `SUM` is correct. When there is a multiple match in any joined table the entire output row becomes multiple and the data that is being summed (or counted or aggregated in any other way) also gets summed multiple times. Try this:

```
SELECT      txt_orditems_pname,
            SUM(mon_orditems_pprice) AS prodTotal,
            COUNT(uid_orderitems) AS prodCount
FROM        dbo.tbl_orders
INNER JOIN  dbo.tbl_orderitems ON (dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders = dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_orderid)
INNER JOIN  
(
    SELECT  x.uid_pay_orderid
    FROM    dbo.tbl_payment x
    GROUP   BY x.uid_pay_orderid
) AS payments ON (dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders = payments.uid_pay_orderid)

WHERE
  uid_orditems_orderid = 61571
GROUP BY
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname
ORDER BY
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname
```

I don't know what data from `tbl_payment` you are using, are any of the columns from the SELECT list actually from `tbl_payment`? Why is `tbl_payment` being joined?

Comment: Thanks for your response, the `mon_orditems_pprice is from `tbl_orditems` table. Thanks for the lead though i will adjust and report back.

Comment: Hi Ivan, i am using the payment table for drilling down the data which will be included in the where statements.

Comment: Hi Jason. The way i wrote it in my query won't cause multiple rows any more but it also isn't useful (no data or filtering is being performed, just the joining). Try to give an example of what data or filtering from `tbl_payments` you need...

Comment: Sorry Ivan I just wanted to get the query running first. The payment table holds payment status info, i.e paid, deposit payment, final payment etc, i was just going to put a where statement like `WHERE dbo.tbl_payment.txt_pay_status = 'Paid'` etc? Is there a more efficient way to do this? PS. I really appreciate your help!! Thank you.

Comment: OK, so you want only orders that have been paid for? Is it possible that there are, for instance 2 rows in `tbl_payment` for a single order and one has `txt_pay_status` `Paid` while the other has some other value? Do you need only those orders whose all payments have status `Paid`?

Comment: There will be a few things i need to drill for, date range, webid, pre-order, order status, product category, product sub category. If you can give me 5 mins i will add the columns etc, if you show me how to do one, i am more than willing to do the rest, i do not like to impose!!

Comment: Sorry, i did not answer your question. When there are multiple payments payments, the order will be a pre order. This is where customers pay a deposit, and then make a final payment prior to delivery. One payment would have a status of Deposit payment (initial payment) and the other would be Final Payment (when the order is completed) i need data when the order is completed.

Comment: No problem, if you have any questions regarding any specific query or situation the SO folks will be glad to help out :)